# Why does a property created with Object.defineProperty in a decorator not show up on the object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I want to validate the value of a property when it is set, by adding a decorator in the class definition.

```js
function Test() {
    return (target: object, key: string) => {
        let val = '';
        Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
            get: () => val,
            set: (v: string) => {
                if(/.*\s.*/.test(v)) throw new Error(`Id '${v}' must not contain any whitespace!`)
                val = v;
            },
            enumerable: true
        });
    }
}

class FooClazz {
    @Test()
    id: string;

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

const test = new FooClazz("myId");

console.log(Object.keys(test)) // -> [];
```

The setter validator works, but when I try to log out the object or its keys, `id` does not show up. Even though I set `enumerable` to `true`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `Test` decorator decorates the `prototype` property of the `FooClazz` class. But you're trying to get *own* keys of `FooClazz`'s instance. While `id` property exists on it's prototype chain:

```js
console.log(Object.keys(test.__proto__)) // -> ["id"];
```

Yet another problem is `Test` decorator runs only once (when decorates `FooClazz`'s prototype) and `val` variable is 'shared' among the instances (though it may be intentional?).

```js
const test = new FooClazz("myId");
const anotherTest = new FooClazz("anotherId");

console.log(test.id);         // -> "anotherId"
console.log(anotherTest.id);  // -> "anotherId"
```

You may use a trick with redefining the key on the instance itself on the first set:

```ts
function Test(target: any, key: string) {
    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
        get: () => '',
        set: function(v: string) {
            var val = '';
            Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
                get: () => val,
                set: (v: string) => {
                    if(/.*\s.*/.test(v)) throw new Error(`Id '${v}' must not contain any whitespace!`)
                    val = v;
                },
                enumerable: true,
            });
            this[key] = v;
        },
    }); 
}

class FooClazz {
    @Test
    id: string;

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBzgkN)

Comment: Thank you a lot! This works and your explanation was great!

Answer (score 0):

You add a property to `FooClazz` in this case (not to an instance of `FooClazz` such as `test`), which doesn't do anything for its instances.

To make sure that `test`, an instance of `FooClazz`, gets the property, you'll need to define it on `FooClazz`'s prototype:

```
function Test() {
    return (target: any, key: string) => {
        
        target.prototype = target.prototype  || {};
        let val = '';
         Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, key, {
            get: () => val,
            set: (v: string) => {
                if(/.*\s.*/.test(v)) throw new Error(`Id '${v}' must not contain any whitespace!`)
                val = v;
            },
            enumerable: true
        });
    }
}

class FooClazz {
    @Test()
    id: string;

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

const test = new FooClazz("myId");
console.log(Object.keys(test));
```

[Working version on the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAFQKYGcoAoCUiDeAUIiYgE6pQhlJZQCGZA5pQFyL1gCeANIgNaou7TGRhgmeALwA+AsVKKFikg2aUAdAAcycKHq5bUiKYjUso23fqiHjiAD4OCAXwDcylQBtKiAG70XiaIAOQhHiqKAPIARgBWqNAaACaowOKoAAq6RmS2dIwWVnoGRnyCvPKRkRbsuCZyAV48ntWI6GyIWH4iUGIS0nJEbW0wwFgA9BoAVAA66DNTUBjYfjh4UAAWugDuiGCoewCiZLpkWAAGAJLJoQAk+H4uIYgAtiCY+3qIEAgM4hxuIgdpsYMt0Fp6BBUABCC44VojEhNYJ+CJIxAuFoYxCoMAgV6oMj0GI+dh9ECoREkFw4dE0wguQiECBeejodCIABicDgAGE2QAvQVVUgAATQmFwnhgyV6-SYHk8vzAohA0Dg51l8vEklFkS2MAWsuCsvpmMZzJVn3BUGCBz2PP5QsFWAARK8uDc3XSWQh0HAfBovHAmFhYgkkhV0HQVus3EA).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. While it does show the right keys, the setter is only called when you define the property on the target itself. You can check that by adding a `console.log("evaluated")` in the set function.