# Angular FormGroup patchValue/setValue doesn't trigger property decorator's getter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I'm trying to use a custom property decorator called `@Amount()` that would eventually format the property value into a specific format that I need.

**amount.decorator.ts**

```
export const Amount = () => 
  (target: any, key: string) => {
    let _value: number | string = target[key];

    if (delete target[key]) {
      return Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: true,
        get: () => {
          console.log("returning", "$" + _value);
          return "$" + _value;
        },
        set: (val) => {
          console.log("setting val", val);
          _value = val;
        },
      });
    }
  }
```

**summary.model.ts**

```
export class Summary {
  regularField!: string;
  @Amount() amountField!: number | string;
}
```

**form.component.ts**

```
export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {
  summary: Summary;
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    regularField: new FormControl(''),
    amountField: new FormControl('Initial value'),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.summary = this.service.getSummary();
    // summary.regularField is "Hello world!"
    // summary.amountField is 123.00
    
    this.summary.amountField = 456.00; <-- triggers "setting val" comment as expected

    console.log(this.summary.amountField); <-- triggers "returning" comment from @Amount() as expected 

    console.log(this.form.controls['amountField'].value); <-- shows "Initial value"

    this.form.patchValue(this.summary || {}); <-- expectation is the getter is called in order to patch it to the formcontrol, but it is not is called

    console.log(this.form.controls['amountField'].value); <-- still shows "Initial value"
  }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing, or some internal logic I'm misunderstanding about patchValue that making it not retrieve the amountField property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what's happening, you need to see the implementation of `patchvalue`/`setValue()` :

```
 (Object.keys(value) as Array<keyof TControl>).forEach(name => {
      assertControlPresent(this, true, name as any);
      (this.controls as any)[name].setValue(
          (value as any)[name], {onlySelf: true, emitEvent: options.emitEvent});
    });
```

As you can see it iterates over the keys of the `value` to update the controls.

Here is a decorator that fixes your issue :

```
export const Amount = () => (target: any, key: string) => {
  let _value: number | string = target[key];

  Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
    get: () => '',
    set: function (v: string) {
      var val = '';
      Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
        get: () => {
          console.log('returning', '$' + _value);
          return '$' + _value;
        },
        set: (val) => {
          console.log('setting val', val);
          _value = val;
        },
        enumerable: true,
      });
      this[key] = v;
    },
  });
};
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68194519/884123) for the reason why.

Comment: I've tried it without deleting the target[key] and it doesn't change anything. If I can't use defineProperty, is there an alternative that will work?